# OperationalError 1054, "Unknown column 'xx' in 'field list'"

Tags: python, django

Creating a registration form for users to fill out after signup, but, during testing, the data that is posting from my register function in views.py, generates an operational error, Unknown column 'realname' in field list. I have realname, in my models.py, and form.py. As well I have synced it with django and done my migrations with south. Need help troubleshooting the cause!

**Models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ProfileUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    realname = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=254, blank=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_images/', blank=True)

    #admin level and additional infomation
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    #Override the _unicode_() method to return out something meaningful
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s %s' % (self.realname, self.birthday, self.city, self.state, self.image) 


class ProfileStatsUser(models.Model):
    profileuser = models.OneToOneField(ProfileUser)
    user_title = models.CharField(max_length=254, verbose_name="Influencer Level", blank=True)
    user_points = models.IntegerField(null=False, verbose_name="Style Points", blank=True)


    def _unicode_(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.user_title, self.user_points)
```

**forms.py:**

```
#coding=utf-8
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.forms import extras
from models import ProfileUser, ProfileStatsUser
import time

now=time.localtime()

###### Login for users ###########
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username=forms.CharField(label=_(u"username"),max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 20,}))
    password=forms.CharField(label=_(u"password"),max_length=30,widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'size': 20,}))

    class Meta:
        """docstring for Meta"""
        model = User


###### Signup for users ###########
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email=forms.EmailField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email', 'required':True}))
    username=forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username','required':True}))
    password=forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password','required':True}))
    password2=forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Re-Enter Password','required':True}))


    class Meta:
        """ To Specify the fields from User model from django, and to prevent abstraction"""
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password', 'password2']


    def clean_username(self):
        users = User.objects.filter(username__iexact=self.cleaned_data["username"])
        if not users:
            return self.cleaned_data["username"]
        raise forms.ValidationError("This username already exist")

    def clean_email(self):
        emails = User.objects.filter(email__iexact=self.cleaned_data["email"])
        if not emails:
            return self.cleaned_data["email"]
        raise forms.ValidationError("Email is already registered")

    def clean_password2(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")

        if not password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must confirm your password")

        if password != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The password does not match ")

        return password2

###### Registration for users ###########
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    realname=forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Real Name','required':True}))
    birthday=forms.DateField(label=_(u"birthdate(mm/dd/yy)"),widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1900, now[0]+1)),required=False)
    city=forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'City','required':True}))
    state=forms.CharField(max_length=2, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'State','required':True}))
    image = forms.ImageField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        """ To Specify the fields from User model and the extension of the user model from django, and to prevent abstraction"""
        model = ProfileUser
        fields = ['realname', 'birthday','city','state','image']



###### Profile for users ###########
class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
    realname=forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Real Name','required':True}))
    email=forms.EmailField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required':False}))
    username=forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required':False}))
    birthday=forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'required':False}))
    city=forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required':False}))
    state=forms.CharField(max_length=2, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required':False}))

    class Meta:
        """ To Specify the fields from User model and the extension of the user model from django, and to prevent abstraction"""
        model = ProfileUser
        fields = ['realname', 'birthday','city', 'state', 'email', 'username']
```

**views.py:**

```
#coding=utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as auth_login ,logout as auth_logout
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from forms import LoginForm, SignupForm, RegisterForm, ProfileForm
from models import ProfileUser, ProfileStatsUser
from PIL import Image


###### Login for users ###########
def login(request):
    template_var={}
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST.copy())
        if form.is_valid():
            login(request,form.cleaned_data["username"],form.cleaned_data["password"])
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("login"))
    template_var["form"]=form
    return render_to_response("registration/login.html",template_var,context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def _login(request,username,password):
    ret=False
    user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)
    if user:
        if user.is_active:
            auth_login(request,user)
            ret=True
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, _(u'user is not active'))
    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, _(u'user not exsist'))
    return ret


###### Signup for users ###########
def signup(request):
    template_var={}
    form = SignupForm()
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=SignupForm(request.POST.copy())
        if form.is_valid():
            username=form.cleaned_data["username"]
            email=form.cleaned_data["email"]
            password=form.cleaned_data["password"]
            user=User.objects.create_user(username,email,password)
            user.save()
            _login(request,username,password)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("register")
    template_var["form"]=form
    return render_to_response("registration/signup.html",template_var,context_instance=RequestContext(request))

###### Registration for users ###########
def register(request):
    template_var={}
    form = RegisterForm()  
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method=="POST":
           form=RegisterForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
           if form.is_valid():
                realname=form.cleaned_data["realname"]
                birthday=form.cleaned_data["birthday"]
                city = form.cleaned_data["city"]
                state = form.cleaned_data["state"]   
                reqfile = request.FILES.get("image", False)
                registeruser=ProfileUser.objects.create(user=request.user, birthday=birthday,
                    city=city, state=state, image=reqfile)
                registeruser.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("dashboard"))          
        template_var["form"]=form        
        return render_to_response("registration/register.html",template_var,context_instance=RequestContext(request))   


###### Profile for users ###########
def dashboard(request):
    template_var={}
    form=ProfileForm()
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = ProfileUser.objects.get(user=request.user)
        first_name=user.first_name
        last_name=user.last_name
        email=user.email
        username=user.username
        birthday=user.birthday
        city=user.city
        state=user.state

        #None form elements
        title=user.user_title
        points=user.user_points
        image=user.image
        template_var["title"]=title
        template_var["points"]=points
        template_var["image"]=image

        template_var["form"]=form  
        template_var["is_authenticated"]= True
    return render_to_response("userprofile/dashboard.html",template_var)
```

**Traceback information:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup/register/

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 2.7.1
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'home',
 'profiles',
 'south')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/amechiegbe/Desktop/cm_dev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/amechiegbe/Desktop/cm_dev/Indieitude/profiles/views.py" in register
  73.                     city=city, state=state, image=reqfile)
File "/Users/amechiegbe/Desktop/cm_dev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in create
  157.         return self.get_queryset().create(**kwargs)
File "/Users/amechiegbe/Desktop/cm_dev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in create
  319.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
File "/Users/amechiegbe/Desktop/cm_dev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  545.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/Users/amechiegbe/Desktop/cm_dev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  573.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "/Users/amechiegbe/Desktop/cm_dev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  654.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "/Users/amechiegbe/Desktop/cm_dev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  687.                                using=using, raw=raw)
File "/Users/amechiegbe/Desktop/cm_dev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  232.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/Users/amechiegbe/Desktop/cm_dev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1511.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/Users/amechiegbe/Desktop/cm_dev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  899.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/amechiegbe/Desktop/cm_dev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  69.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/amechiegbe/Desktop/cm_dev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/amechiegbe/Desktop/cm_dev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  99.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/Users/amechiegbe/Desktop/cm_dev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/amechiegbe/Desktop/cm_dev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  124.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "/Users/amechiegbe/Desktop/cm_dev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  205.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/Users/amechiegbe/Desktop/cm_dev/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  36.     raise errorclass, errorvalue

Exception Type: OperationalError at /signup/register/
Exception Value: (1054, "Unknown column 'realname' in 'field list'")
```

Comment: did you add `realname` _after_ doing a syncdb on the model once ?

Comment: Too much code here, but not the actual relevant thing: the exact error message and traceback that would enable us to see where the error is coming from.

Comment: Just added the error message! and @karthikr yes I added realname after I did syncdb, then I ran it again to add just in case, as well do the south migration.

Comment: Did you apply the south migrations as well? Happened to me once - created migrations but forgot to apply them.

Comment: Syncdb does not understand changes to schema. South would be the way to go

Comment: Many thanks! elssar and karthikr. South was the way to go! I need to inspectdb, then alter my models to what was displayed from inspectdb, and change it after i ran the migrations!